# Command line volume control amixer has problems with muting

Tags: command-line, alsa, volume-control

Because my laptop volume controls are state of the art in the field of bad usability, I decided to map two keyboard shortcuts to make my own volume controls. I found that `amixer` should be helpful:

```
Super+Arrow Up        amixer set Master playback 2dB+
Super+Arrow Down      amixer set Master playback 2dB-
```

This works, but if I turn the volume too low, I cannot take it back. It stays muted and my "volume up" command does nothing. When I try these commands in terminal, it gives following outputs:

```
$ amixer set Master playback 2dB-
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono: Playback 4 [6%] [-45.00dB] [on]
$ amixer set Master playback 2dB-
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono: Playback 1 [2%] [-47.25dB] [on]
$ amixer set Master playback 2dB-
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono: Playback 0 [0%] [-99999.99dB] [on]
```

And now it is broken. Following does nothing:

```
$ amixer set Master playback 2dB+
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono: Playback 0 [0%] [-99999.99dB] [on]
```

I have to use my mouse, grab volume toggle on my panel and raise it manually. The value `[-99999.99dB]` looks suspicious, but I have no idea what does it mean.

**Could anyone adjust my two volume commands they could avoid such issue?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug, you should report it.

Meanwhile, you could instead use

```
amixer set Master playback 3+
amixer set Master playback 3-
```

Comment: Brilliant! `amixer set Master playback 3-` comes with the suspicious value -99999.99dB too, but it is actually able to go back and raise the volume. As you suggested, I filed the bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-utils/+bug/1078233 Thank you!